# Copying & pasting drop down lists clears cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown, copy-paste

So I'm quite new to script, and I've got some working dynamic dependent drop down lists. When I clear a cell in column A, it clears the cell directly to the right of it, which is great.

However, when I copy and paste a row, it clears the cell to the right of column A. My question is: **Is there a way to make a row "copy & paste-able", so it doesn't clear column B when pasting?**

Here are some images of what I'm describing:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0xOg.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/geHuu.png

Lastly, here's the script that I'm using:

```
function onEdit(){
    var tabLists = "Exercise Index";
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp;
    var activeSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var data = spreadsheet.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabLists);
    
    var activeCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
    
    if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 3 && activeSheet.getSheetName().includes("Week")){
      
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
      
      var makes = data.getRange(1, 1, 1, data.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      
      var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
      
      if(makeIndex != 0){
      
          var validationRange = data.getRange(2, makeIndex, data.getLastRow());
          var validationRule = spreadsheet.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
          activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    
      }  
        
    }
    
  }
```

Copy of the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OrDTJiAlVJRU5tKCA55CoVgnT83_k8n_yz9BkWYpZ_0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Is there a way to make a row "copy & paste-able", so it doesn't clear column B when pasting?`. And also, I cannot understand your 2 images. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "about the detail of them", but I can try another explanation. I have copied (Ctrl+C) and pasted (Ctrl+V) some rows. When I do so, like in Image 1, it clears the cell in column B. In image 2, after I paste multiple rows, only the first row of column B is cleared. I'm asking: Is there a way to copy and paste without column B clearing, using my current script?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your replying, I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to `activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations()`. When your script is run, the right side cell of the active cell is cleared. So, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
```

#### To:

```
activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
```

Or, remove `activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();`.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike! I had tried removing `clearDataValidations();`, but for some reason, it didn't occur to me to try removing `clearContent()`.

Comment: @Thomas Johnston Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I appreciate that you help me to make understand your question. Thank you, too.